# Where I can Clear Session Variable

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Im a newboy in .net please help ,I am using a Session Variable for storing some values in aspx Page. Actually I want to clear session values when user Leave page to go other page. I know there is PageUnload Event where I can Clear Session but i need to clear session only after the User leaves a Page.

Is there other way to clear Session variables in aspx page.???

Comment: this is usefull for u -http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session variable is for storing data that is using for single user in all pages. You don't have to use it in your scenario. Use ViewState or page variables against.

Answer (score 11):

On the other pages , where you are going after leaving current page, use..

`Session.Remove("Variable_name");` .

Comment: and you must be having so many pages, right? Actually i was also facing the same problem yesterday, but thanks to god, i had 2 masterpages, in which i have changed and it worked wonder !! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Session.Contents.Remove("mysession");
```

or

```
Session.Contents.RemoveAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to clear only the values you need to, however if you want to clear the entire session then:

```
Session.Clear()
```

Comment: I just need where I can clear my Session Variable in First time leaving the Page.in Which Event?

Comment: There is no leaving page event in asp.net you'd have to catch that in JS and then run the back end code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.Abandon();
```

or more effective

```
Session["your_session_name"]="";
```